# How to send Blank Array when no data found?

Tags: php, arrays, api, codeigniter

I developed State->city->area wise selection in PHP.
All things works fine. But there is no data found in `city` there it removed `city` array.
I want to pass Empty `city array` to API response When no data found from database. How can I do this ?

My code look like this

```
if (isset($credentials->credentials->uid) && $credentials->credentials->uid != ""):
                        $mainArr = array();
                        $stateArr = array();
                        $state = $this->Data_model->Custome_query('SELECT mf_state_id, name, status FROM mf_state WHERE status = "A"');
                        foreach ($state as $s) {
                            $sArr = array();
                            $sArr = array(
                                'mf_state_id' => $s['mf_state_id'],
                                'name' => $s['name'],
                                'status' => $s['status']
                            );
                            $cityArr = array();
                            $city = $this->Data_model->Custome_query('SELECT mf_city_id, mf_state_id, name, status, active FROM mf_city WHERE status = "A" AND active = "S" AND mf_state_id = '.$s['mf_state_id']);
                            foreach ($city as $c) {
                                $cArr = array();
                                $cArr = array(
                                    'mf_city_id' => $c['mf_city_id'],
                                    'mf_state_id' => $c['mf_state_id'],
                                    'name' => $c['name'],
                                    'status' => $c['status'],
                                    'active' => $c['active']
                                );
                                $areaArr = array();
                                $area = $this->Data_model->Custome_query('SELECT mf_area_id, mf_city_id, area, status FROM mf_area WHERE status = "A" AND mf_city_id = '.$c['mf_city_id']);
                                foreach ($area as $a) {
                                    $aArr = array();
                                    $aArr = array(
                                        'mf_area_id' => $a['mf_area_id'],
                                        'mf_city_id' => $a['mf_city_id'],
                                        'area' => $a['area'],
                                        'status' => $a['status'],
                                    );



                                    $areaArr[] = $aArr;
                                    $cArr['area'] = $areaArr;
                                }


                                // print_r($cityArr);
                                    $cityArr[] = $cArr;
                                    $sArr['cities'] = $cityArr;
                                    // print_r($sArr['cities']);

                                }
                                $stateArr[] = $sArr;
                            }

                            // print_r($sArr['cities']);
                            $mainArr = $stateArr;


                        echo str_replace("\/", "/", json_encode( ['res' => 0, 'msg' => 'Successfully got City Area data', 'data' => $mainArr, 'version' => $this->version,"qry"=>""]));
```

and response I am getting is look like this

```
{
    "res": 0,
    "msg": "Successfully got City Area data",
    "data": [
        {
            "mf_state_id": "1",
            "name": "Gujarat",
            "status": "A",
            "cities": [
                {
                    "mf_city_id": "1",
                    "mf_state_id": "1",
                    "name": "Surat",
                    "status": "A",
                    "active": "S",
                    "area": [
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "1",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Adajan",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "2",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Bhatar",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "3",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Dindoli",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "4",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Kapodra",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "5",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Mota Varachha",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "6",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Nana Varachha",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "7",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Palanpur Patiya",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "8",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Parvat Patiya",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "9",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Udhna",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "10",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Athwa",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "11",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Bhatha",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "12",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Ghoddod Road",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "13",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Katargam",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "14",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Pandesara",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "15",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Piplod",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "16",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Vesu",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "17",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Citylight",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "18",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Jahangirpura",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "19",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Pal",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "20",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Parle Point",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "21",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Rander",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "28",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Zampa Bazaar",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "40",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Rander Road",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "43",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Varachha Road",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "58",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Palanpur Gam",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "63",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Palanpur Jakatnaka",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "92",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "New Causeway Road",
                            "status": "A"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "mf_state_id": "2",
            "name": "Maharastra",
            "status": "A"
        }
    ],
    "version": "1.0",
    "qry": ""
}
```

In last `state` `Maharastra` there is no city in data base.
but it should return `city` array blank.

**I want response look like this. City array should come null array when Data not found**

```
{
    "res": 0,
    "msg": "Successfully got City Area data",
    "data": [
        {
            "mf_state_id": "1",
            "name": "Gujarat",
            "status": "A",
            "cities": [
                {
                    "mf_city_id": "1",
                    "mf_state_id": "1",
                    "name": "Surat",
                    "status": "A",
                    "active": "S",
                    "area": [
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "1",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Adajan",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "2",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Bhatar",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "3",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Dindoli",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "4",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Kapodra",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "5",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Mota Varachha",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "6",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Nana Varachha",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "7",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Palanpur Patiya",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "8",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Parvat Patiya",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "9",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Udhna",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "10",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Athwa",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "11",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Bhatha",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "12",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Ghoddod Road",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "13",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Katargam",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "14",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Pandesara",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "15",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Piplod",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "16",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Vesu",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "17",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Citylight",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "18",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Jahangirpura",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "19",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Pal",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "20",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Parle Point",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "21",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Rander",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "28",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Zampa Bazaar",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "40",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Rander Road",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "43",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Varachha Road",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "58",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Palanpur Gam",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "63",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "Palanpur Jakatnaka",
                            "status": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "mf_area_id": "92",
                            "mf_city_id": "1",
                            "area": "New Causeway Road",
                            "status": "A"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "mf_state_id": "2",
            "name": "Maharastra",
            "status": "A",
            "cities": []

        }
    ],
    "version": "1.0",
    "qry": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize the `$sArr` with cities key as empty array. If the cities are then found of the state, the `cities` key will be overwritten in the loop else you will get empty values.

```
                            $sArr = array();
                            $sArr = array(
                                'mf_state_id' => $s['mf_state_id'],
                                'name' => $s['name'],
                                'status' => $s['status'],
                                'cities' => array(),    //Initialize with empty array here.
                            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, If state have no cities or empty then other code does not execute.

```
if(count($city)>0){
    foreach ($city as $c) {
        $cArr = array(
            'mf_city_id' => $c['mf_city_id'],
            'mf_state_id' => $c['mf_state_id'],
            'name' => $c['name'],
            'status' => $c['status'],
            'active' => $c['active']
        );
    }
}else{
    $cArr = array();
}
```